# pheatmap: manually re-order leaves in dendogram

Tags: r, dendrogram, pheatmap, iris-dataset

I have created a heatmap with a corresponding dendogram based on hierarchical clustering with `{pheatmap}`. I would like to change the order of the leaves in the dendogram, manually, based on what I see visually.

First, can anyone confirm that this is statistically correct and allowed? (in theory that should not change the between-cluster distance, but maybe I am wrong).

Second, any suggestions on how to change the order of the leaves would be appreciated!

A reproductible example with the iris data:

```
data(iris)
pheatmap(iris[1:4], cutree_cols = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example you can use a callback function to reorder the columns, e.g.

```r
library(pheatmap)
data(iris)
colnames(iris)
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"

callback = function(hc, mat){
  sv = svd(t(mat))$v[,c(1)]
  dend = reorder(as.dendrogram(hc), wts = sv^2)
  as.hclust(dend)
}

#svd(t(iris[c(4, 2, 3, 1)]))$v[,1]

pheatmap(iris[c(4, 2, 3, 1)], cutree_cols = 3, clustering_callback = callback)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

For your actual data, you will probably need to fiddle around with the weights to get the columns in your desired order, e.g.

```r
library(pheatmap)
data(iris)
colnames(iris)
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"

callback = function(hc, mat){
  sv = svd(t(mat))$v[,c(2)]
  dend = reorder(as.dendrogram(hc), wts = sv)
  as.hclust(dend)
}

#svd(t(iris[c(4, 2, 3, 1)]))$v[,2]

pheatmap(iris[c(4, 2, 3, 1)], cutree_cols = 3, clustering_callback = callback)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This feature is described briefly at the end of the help file:

```
?pheatmap
...

# Modify ordering of the clusters using clustering callback option
callback = function(hc, mat){
    sv = svd(t(mat))$v[,1]
    dend = reorder(as.dendrogram(hc), wts = sv)
    as.hclust(dend)
}

pheatmap(test, clustering_callback = callback)

## Not run: 
# Same using dendsort package
library(dendsort)

callback = function(hc, ...){dendsort(hc)}
pheatmap(test, clustering_callback = callback)

## End(Not run)
```

Comment: I used dendsort package, very fast and easy (because I can't do manual reordering of subjects, there is to much! but automated reordering of the branchs according to weight with the callback function is nice! thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired output in your example, you can add `cluster_cols=F`, reorder the columns manually, and add `gaps_col` to specify the gaps manually:

```
data(iris)

pheatmap::pheatmap(
  iris[c(4,2,3,1)],
  cluster_cols=F,
  cluster_rows=F,
  gaps_col=c(1,3)
)
```

You can also use `reorder.hclust` from `vegan` to reorder the branches of the clustering tree without having to convert the `hclust` object to a dendrogram and back. Often a good weight for reordering the branches is the first dimension in a PCA of the input (or MDS if the input is a distance matrix):

```
data(iris)

df=iris[1:4]
library(vegan) # for reorder.hclust
hc=reorder(hclust(dist(t(scale(df)))),prcomp(t(scale(df)))$x[,1])
# hc=reorder(hclust(as.dist(df)),cmdscale(df)[,1]) # for distance matrix

pheatmap::pheatmap(
  df,
  cluster_rows=F,
  clustering_callback=\(...)hc,
  cutree_cols=3
)
```